# What function could be workaround of this Scratch block in Python?

Tags: python, mit-scratch

I want to know, what is a workaround/replacement for this Scratch block:

[image: (letter (...) of (...))]

In Python. I know that in JavaScript, the answer is:

```js
"..."[... - 1]
```

Comment: Have you ever actually tried to *use* Python?

Comment: Yes, I know it. Much.

Comment: *Half a beginner, half not. But I still know much

Comment: could you please explain the ask in more detail; i'm not familiar with javascript and I don't get what is it that you want

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt i know being told that you should do research and tests yourself before asking sounds irritating at first but it is a fact really.

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt [Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is accepted, even encouraged. But don't use a comment for that; please post an answer. Oh, and using capitals doesn't make the message clearer.

Comment: @RuudHelderman OK, but why can I only accept my answer in 2 hours?

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt SO policies are discussed on [meta]. As has been done here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is the same as in JavaScript, like:

```js
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
var letter1 = alphabet[0]
var letter2 = alphabet[1]
var letter3 = alphabet[2]
var letter123 = letter1 + letter2 + letter3

alert("The first three letters of the alphabet are: " + letter123)
```

**I was very d**b**